# Timezone conflicts from user setup to visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, administration, timezone, user-admin

I have a user that is set up in the right time zome from the admin section.
If I do:

```
system.debug(UserInfo.getTimeZone());
```

it shows properly as well.
However when I bring the results into my VF page, (the results comes from a soql that i JSON Serialize to be use in a JS pluggin) the times get corrupted and get added 11 extra hours.

Is there an extra set up that I need to do?

Comment: SOQL queries return dateTime field values as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) values. Somewhere I've read that the `DateTime` fields will be converted into user's time zone whenever they get rendered in Visualforce

Comment: While serializing the DateTime with JSON the time is converted to the **local** time zone, your local time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In database dateTime field values stored as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

When you refer the field into VF page, It will display the UTC dateTime.

So what we can do to fix this.

1. You can use `<apex:outputField value="your field" />`  So `apex:outputField` will format/change the dateTime value based on user timeZone.
2. If you can't use `apex:outputField` then try to format your datetime field in controller side then display in VF page.

   `String strActivityDateTime = obj.ActivityDateTime.format(' MMMM d\', \'yyyy \'at\' hh:mm a', UserInfo.getTimeZone().getId());`

So it will format your dateTime based on current user's TimeZone.

Since you are using JSON so 2 option is good for you.